# Ubuntu 18.04 server unable to ping websites but can ping IP addresses

Tags: networking, server, dns, ping

Total newbie here, got fed up with Windows world and gone over to the dark side

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 18.4 LTS on VirtualBox with bridge connections.

It seems I can ping IP addresses internally, ping with IP addresses externally but when I try to resolve hostnames or websites, I can't.

```
rahim@websrv01ubuntu:~$ ping -c3 192.168.0.1PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.20 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=9.16 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=7.38 ms

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.206/6.584/9.164/2.497 ms
```

---

```
rahim@websrv01ubuntu:~$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=121 time=34.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=121 time=22.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=121 time=27.8 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.980/28.526/34.788/4.849 ms
rahim@websrv01ubuntu:~$ ping -c3 websvr01ubuntu
ping: websvr01ubuntu: Temporary failure in name resolution
rahim@websrv01ubuntu:~$ ping -c3 www.google.com
PING www.google.com(ams16s32-in-x04.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400e:80c::2004)) 56 data bytes


--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2042ms
```

I know 18.04 uses netplan and this is how it the `50-cloud-init.yaml` file is configured for static IP address.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.200/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

---

```
rahim@websrv01ubuntu:~$ ping -c3 google.com
PING google.com(ams16s32-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e)) 56 data bytes


--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2038ms
```

---

```
rahim@websrv01ubuntu:~$ ping -c3 www.google.com
PING www.google.com(ams15s21-in-x04.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400e:800::2004)) 56 data bytes


--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2034ms
```

---

```
rahim@websrv01ubuntu:~$ ping -c3 www.servingyoubetter.co.uk
PING fwd3.hosts.co.uk (85.233.160.22) 56(84) bytes of data.


--- fwd3.hosts.co.uk ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2055ms
```

Comment: unfortunately my formatting isn't comming through properly for the .yaml file but i have taken into consideration of the 2 space indentation restriction for .yaml files~

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your server is trying to use IPV6 while it might be unproperly configured. You could try disable ipv6 if not used or check your ipv6 configuration.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-ipv6-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Answer (score 2):

Check the answer from olivierb2. If still doesn't work, maybe is a problem of `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
$ sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak
$ echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > temp
$ sudo cp temp /etc/resolv.conf
```